# Use apache commons-exec to run git clone: how to input password?

Tags: java, git, apache-commons-exec

I try to use apache commons-exec to run git clone command but stuck, it did not prompt me with password input at all and block there.

```
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.setStreamHandler( new PumpStreamHandler( System.out, System.err, System.in ) );
executor.execute( "git clone --progress -v https://xxx/prj.git" );
```

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out a way to work around this problem, just wrap the user name and passwd as inputstream:

```
String input="...";        
executor.setStreamHandler( new PumpStreamHandler( System.out, System.err, new ByteArrayInputStream(
            input.getBytes() ) ) );
```

Comment: What is the input string format in this case? Do you know if this works for git pull?